# How can i give support Multiple Device Support in react native?

Tags: android, ios, css, react-native

Explanation:

I have created an application in which it's looking well in an android phone(480x320, such type of devices) and iPhone 7 plus and below. When I run my application into the tablet Nexus 7(nougat). It reduces the font size, Images and even height(which specify in the CSS) of my views.

In Android, we have different types of the drawable folder to easily manage multiple device support based on the values folder also.

Problem: How can I manage my application which will run on all the devices including phone and table in Android and iPhone and iPad in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you asked THE question. Looking through the react native elements library I found a function they call normalizeText, you can find it here:

https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/helpers/normalizeText.js

Basically they take the pixel-ratio api, which docs you can find here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html

and depending on the screen size they multiply the values of with/height/font using that functions with values from 0.5 to 2. I found it a good solution to get a good visuals on every platform.

For the UI I would recommend you to use flex as much as you can, because it gets your app independent of width and height.

If you need some clarification feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Can we use MediaQuery library for this? Have you used it?

Comment: I have not used it but seems to be fine, use it if you feel like it.

Comment: Sure why not? What about for the iPad and Tablet?

Comment: I found a link where same thing is mentioned. Please refer a link https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html

Comment: On my way, I commented it at the answer though!